# Connectors to sit on rounded surface

Tags: connector, plug, header

[image]Is there such a thing as connectors that sit flush on a rounded surface? Like a crescent shape. Or a flexible connector that would adhere to a rounded shape?

For example, I have a pole with a sensor on the end, I'd like a connector that sits flush on the pole for easy removal instead of a fixed wire running along it.

If so what is the name of such connectors?

I've added a crude drawing, as per request, I'm terrible at anything visual like that.

Comment: Welcome to EESE but please note that direct shopping questions will result in fairly prompt closure of your question as per [site rules](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). You can save your question from closure by editing, removing the shopping part and asking for the name or search term for the type of connector you seek but you'd need to do a much better job of describing it.

Comment: I've added one, however, it is a bit crude. I'm not good with that visual stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have access to a 3-D printer, you can create an adapter such that one surface matches the curve of your cylinder and the other surface is flat to match the connector.

Make the printed adapter such that it has mounting holes that match those in the connector.

You can easily make this waterproof by using sealing tape on both sides of the adapter.  I normally use Very High Bond (VHB) adhesive for this purpose but even silicone sealant will work.  This, of course, assumes that your connector is also waterproof.

My connector of choice for these (low cost) applications is Amp's CPC series.  There are silicone seals that fit inside the connector side with the male pins and the boot is available with a heat-shrink seal if the connector needs to be waterproof.

You can also use military MS series connectors if this needs to be a high-reliability application.  These are also available as waterproof.

Comment: While I was hoping for an off the shelf product, fabricating one does seem to be the only option.

Comment: Problem with having something off-the-shelf is that how does a manufacturer decide what cylinder diameter to stock?  Each user more than likely needs a different diameter.  There probably exists several (or many) such adapters used by OEM across the world but I don't think that they would ever be listed in a catalog somewhere.

Comment: Maybe check on thiniverse to see if someone has already done such a design.  If, so, use that as a starting point. And - perhaps you can upload your adapter design to thingiverse for others to use as a starting point for their designs.